# How do I make a discord bot join a voice channel?

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js, voice

I am simply trying to make a bot join a voice channel as a placeholder so i can make a music bot play 24/7.

One of the codes that I found on stack**overflow** was:

```
  const channel = client.channels.get("mychannelid");
  if (!channel) return console.error("The channel does not exist!");
  channel.join().then(connection => {
    // Yay, it worked!
    console.log("Successfully connected.");
  }).catch(e => {
    // Oh no, it errored! Let's log it to console :)
    console.error(e);
  });
});
```

[but this didn't seem to work for me. This is what the visual studio code output said](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hir0K.png)

Do you know how I could solve this problem or tell me the right way to do this?

Comment: Due to recent updates StackOverflow answers for discord.js are typically outdated. There's not much need to look at them anyway. The [discord.js docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome) have plenty of examples and is very well put together. In this case you'd be wondering why `client.channels.get` isn't a function, so check the [docs on client.channels](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=channels) and you'll see that it's now a `ChannelManager` and you need to access the cache property instead, as in Jakye's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're using Discord.js V12. To get the channel you'll have to use:

```js
client.channels.cache.get("ChannelID")
```

Comment: sorry i just realized it didn't work. i was using another bot that had the same name *:facepalm:*
it just said "The channel does not exist!"
i tried the I.D. and the name.

Comment: Which version of Discord JS are you using? Is the bot able to see the channel?

Comment: I think i have discord JS v.12 i downloaded the latest version like 5 days ago.
there are no restrictions on the channel and my bot has administrator.

Comment: one thing i did notice when i pasted the code back though, is that the output says expected ',' (comma) instead of every '.' (period) there is in the following line:

`client.channels.cache.get("ChannelID")`

Comment: Sorry, just found the answer on discord.js guide. i should've looked there to begin with.
hope i didnt waste your time!